# boolean method in arrays of type class

Tags: java

I have trouble to compile this method. This method is to search in the array of type Event. So say if the month contains [1,2,3,4,5,6,7*,8,9*], it will search the ones with asterisks and return true

```
 public static boolean isSignificant(Event[] month, String SearchValue) 
      {
        boolean isFound = false;
        for(int i = 0; i< month.length && isFound == false; i++)
        {

          if(month[i].contains(SearchValue)) // error on this line
          {
            isFound = true;
          }
        }
        return isFound;
      }
```

Comment: Why do you expect `month[i].contains(SearchValue)` to compile ? `month` is an array, not a `List`. You can't directly call `contains` on an array. Plus, `month` is of type `Event` while you are searching for a `String` - that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to search this pattern

1. `if (value.endsWith("*")) {`
2. `if (value.matches(".*\\*$")) {`
3. `value.matches(".*?\\*$")`

e.g.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    static String[] month = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7*","8","9*"};
    public static boolean isSignificant() 
        {
            boolean isFound = false;
            for(int i=0; i <month.length && isFound == false; i++)
                {
                    if(month[i].endsWith("*")) 
                        {
                            isFound = true;
                        }
                }
            return isFound;
        }

    public static void main(String []args)
        {
            HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
            if(obj.isSignificant())
                {
                    System.out.println("The string ends with *");
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("The string donot end with *");
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jean-François Savard is right, month is of type Event while you are searching for a String. If you explain to me with more info i could help you more, otherwise ill just assume you mean a string array.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String [] array = {"1","2","3","4*"} ; 
        if(isSignificant(array,"*")){
            System.out.println("Found");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
     }

     public static boolean isSignificant(String[] month, String SearchValue) {
        for(int i = 0; i< month.length; i++) {

          if(month[i].contains(SearchValue)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
}
```